# CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "DB Error: no such table"

Tags: civimail

Hello I am getting the below error when going to certain pages in my civicrm install notably after transfering from one server to a new server....the source server does not have this error.....

CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "DB Error: no such table"

```
#0 /data/www/vhosts/....org.jm/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Info.php(124): civicrm_api3("Mailing", "gettokens", (Array:3))
#1 /data/www/vhosts/....org.jm/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Angular/Manager.php(100): CRM_Mailing_Info->getAngularModules()
#2 /data/www/vhosts/....org.jm/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Angular/Manager.php(178): Civi\Angular\Manager->getModules()
#3 /data/www/vhosts/....org.jm/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Angular/AngularLoader.php(216): Civi\Angular\Manager->resolveDefaultModules("civicrm/a")
#4 /data/www/vhosts/....org.jm/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Angular/AngularLoader.php(108): Civi\Angular\AngularLoader->findActiveModules()
#5 /data/www/vhosts/....org.jm/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Angular/Page/Main.php(83): Civi\Angular\AngularLoader->load()
#6 /data/www/vhosts/....org.jm/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Angular/Page/Main.php(69): Civi\Angular\Page\Main->registerResources()
#7 /data/www/vhosts/....org.jm/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(311): Civi\Angular\Page\Main->run((Array:2), NULL)
#8 /data/www/vhosts/....org.jm/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(85): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:12))
#9 /data/www/vhosts/....org.jm/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
#10 /data/www/vhosts/....org.jm/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(444): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#11 /data/www/vhosts/jta.org.jm/httpdocs/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("a")
#12 /data/www/vhosts/jta.org.jm/httpdocs/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#13 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

@trevorforrest I would check that your database has all the same tables as the old server, the error suggests you may have missed a table or something when transferring from the old server to the new server